# Radio buttons with a long label in a small space

Tags: website-design, forms, gui-design

I have 5 radio buttons among which the user can choose: DTP, MMR, POL, HIB or HEP B and a small space in which to show these buttons.

[image]

The problem is that the labels are not very explanatory. If the user is not an expert in the field and doesn't know what the abbreviations mean, the interface becomes unclear.
So I would like to stretch the labels.

For now I have added a tootltip when the user hovers over the code.

[image]

But I don't think this is the best solution.

I can replace the radio buttons with a drop-down list: in this way I could replace the abbreviation with its description.
But I've never loved drop-down lists, I find them uncomfortable and not aesthetically beautiful.

I would prefer that the form was not bigger than `300 x 80px` and the desktop version has priority over mobile (so no mobile first!).

Are there any better solutions I could take?

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Did you consider a combobox? If yes, why not?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I considered it and find it not suitable for my purposes. The search would not be useful and it is too similar to a drop-down list. Thanks anyway for your reply!

Comment: I meant drop down list (bad me, too often it's implemented with same control).

Comment: How about vertical radio list? This way you will have space for the whole label

Comment: @Shaz You're right, but it would take away so much vertical space. I repeat that I would not want to exceed the size `300 x 80px` too much.

Comment: What is the context of these elements?  Are they part of a form? Or some searching filters? Why do you not want to exceed the 80px height?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of lining your buttons in a row, line them up column style with each option in its own row. You will then have the fill screen width for explanation

Comment: I think this is the best approach instead of having to rely on the user to hover each time they use it. Also they might forget what they all mean if they use it again a second time.